# Decimal Casting

Tags: c#, formatting

I have a decimal number like this:

62.000,0000000

I need to cast that decimal into int; it will always have zero decimal numbers; so I wont loose any precision. What I want is this:

62.000

Stored on an int variable in c#.

I try many ways but it always give me an error, that the string isn't in the correct format, this is one of the ways i tryied:

```
int.Parse("62.000,0000000");
```

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: What language is your OS? There might be an issue with the decimal point/comma and the thousands separator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to parse it in the right culture. For example, the German culture uses "." as a group separator and "," as the decimal separator - so this code works:

```
CultureInfo german = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
decimal d = decimal.Parse("62.000,0000000", german);
int i = (int) d;

Console.WriteLine(i); // Prints 62000
```

Is that what you're after? Note that this will then fail if you present it with a number formatted in a different culture...

EDIT: As Reed mentions in his comment, if your real culture is Spain, then exchange "de-DE" for "es-ES" for good measure.

Comment: Perfect answer - just FYI - I'm pretty sure (from one of this other posts), that lidermin's from spain, so using "es-ES" should give him the proper culture.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify your culture correctly:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
int value = (int) decimal.Parse("60.000,000000", ci);
```

If you do this, it will correctly convert the number.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just cast it to int instead of parsing?

Comment: His example works with a string. So who knows where he gets that number from and if he can change the delivery of the decimal to not show the dots and commas and omit the unnecessary precision?